# Some Podcasts are not updating

Tags: 8.1, sync, podcast

For some reason some of the podcasts I am subscribed to on the Podcasts app are not updating. Some update just fine but for some no new episodes are appearing. Is there anyway to deal with this or is it just an annoying Microsoft glitch?

Comment: Can you give an example of a podcast that is not working for you?

Comment: Not Too Deep With Grace Helbig for example, while, other ones (such as the IGN podcasts) work fine. I've checked on other services like Soundcloud that the episodes are out, but they don't appear on the podcasts app.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the RSS Feed? http://nottoodeep.com/rss

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Annoying that I'll have to re-download all the old episodes, but better than nothing! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually not a bug in the podcast app but an old feed that might not get updated anymore. Easiest solution is to search for the feed that's not working right and adding it manually.